# How to make a negative output really negative?

Tags: javascript

I calculate a `var` like this:

`var difference = new - old;`

This outputs either a positive or negative number.

Then:

```
if (difference => 2) {
  text = "2 or more";
} else if (difference < -1) {
  text = "more than 1 behind;
}
```

With this code, even when the `difference` output is `-5000` for example, I still get `2 or more`. Whereas it should be `even less than 1`.

Why? And how to correct?

Comment: `>=` not `=>`, (the equals always goes on the right of the strict inequality)

Comment: It's "greater than or equal", which translates to `>=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the right operator is >= and not =>

Comment: Oh gods...I never realised this could be a problem...yeah, `difference => 2` is an arrow function, which is truthy. So, now typos can be pretty annoying.

Comment: In Javascript, 'Everything With a "Value" is True' :)

Comment: No, not "anything with value". The `a = 0` *has* a value, and the value is zero. But zero if falsey. The boolean `false` also has a value, which is...the boolean `false`. But it is still falsey. The empty string `""` is similarly *a value* but `if ("")` will not pass. Even `null` could be a value. It's the explicit *absence of value* but it's not much different to zero, which is the explicit absence of numeric value. `NaN` is *also a value*. It's not a number but it's definitely *something*. `Number("apple")` isn't nothing. Only *undefined* is a "nothing".

Comment: Oh It is not my terms actually : https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_booleans.asp

Comment: W3Schools is simply wrong. Yet again. They've cleaned up in recent years but still give blatantly wrong information. How is zero *not* a value?

Comment: @AyoubBargach [why not w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: @VLAZ Well you convinced with your final statement :)

Answer (score 1):

The `=>` is arrow function  in js    see [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

You should use this

```
if (difference >= 2) {
      text = "2 or more";
    } else if (difference < -1) {
      text = "more than 1 behind;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (difference >= 2) {
  text = "2 or more";
} else if (difference < -1) {
  text = "more than 1 behind;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code plugged into a function.

Make sure you are using the math symbol for inequality `>=`.

```js
function check(difference){
text = "";
if (difference >= 2) {
  text = "2 or more";
} else if (difference < -1) {
  text = "more than 1 behind";
}
return difference + ": " + text;
}


console.log(check(-3))
console.log(check(-2))
console.log(check(-1))
console.log(check(0))
console.log(check(1))
console.log(check(2))
console.log(check(3))
console.log(check(4))
console.log(check(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use comparison operator is this >=

```
if (difference >= 2) {
  text = "2 or more";
} else if (difference < -1) {
  text = "more than 1 behind;
}
```